# Method as argument for each instance in ActiveRecord `where`

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Can `.where` in active record take a method as an argument?

```
def not_foo?
  name != "foo"
end
```

The below code does not work, but you'll see what I mean:

```
array.where(|element| element.not_foo?).count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can .where in active record take a method as an argument?

**Ans**: No, it cannot. may be you want to do this

```
array.where.not(name: 'foo').count
```

Answer (score 2):

The pass around methods as arguments, that is functional paradigm. In Ruby that is achieved by `closures`.

`Closures` can be implemented in Ruby through `blocks`, `lambdas`, `procs`.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing several different concepts here.

You can't "pass a method as an argument" in Ruby as you would in C or other languages. You *can* pass a `block` as an argument, which is *very different*.

In your example, `element.not_foo?` would be evaluated first. You are passing the result of that evaluation to `where`. There are, however, some problems in your code which would prevent it from even running:

- The definition of `not_foo?` receives an argument (`def nor_foo?(v)`) but you passed none, which would raise an `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` exception.
- You are using block argument syntax (`|element|`) incorrectly. In any case, ActiveRecord's [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) doesn't accept a block.

Comment: I edited my original question to remove the (v). The second part I kept the same because I didn't know how to make it correct since ActiveRecord doesn't take methods as arguments anyways